# Exposed filter with Load more

Tags: views

I have 2 problems with drupal.org/project/views_load_more & exposed filter:

1. When I change the exposed filter selection, it only filters the result which is in first lot (e.g if I have given a limit of 8 and then change exposed filter selection it filters among those 8 results only).
2. I get duplicate records; if I remove the load more limit I get distinct records

Please help.

Comment: Whic "load more" are we talking about here? Is it https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more ? Please EDIT your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

To address the 2nd bullet of your question, consider using the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. From its project page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.

Comment: I did try the module but My one record is coming in first lot and duplicate record coming when we click on load more.do u know how to solve this ?